# Get today's date in (YYYY-MM-DD) format in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to get today's date in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Any ideas? Using `NOW()` I'm getting hours, minutes and seconds too...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
SELECT CURDATE();
```

[Documentation link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate).

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DATE(NOW())
```

will work for you :)

The [DATE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) converts a datetime into a date.